# How to address a getter from inside the class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, getter, setter

Consider following Kotlin-Code:

```
class Foo(input: Int) {
    private var someField: Int = input
        get() = -field
        set(value) {
            field = -value
        }

    fun bar() {
        println(someField)
    }
}

fun main() {
    Foo(1).bar()
}
```

This prints `-1` in the console which means that inside method `bar()` `someField` references the attribute and not the corresponding getter. Is there a way that allows me to use the `get()`-method as if I was referencing this field from outside?

Comment: Everything's working fine; it's just that the constructor initializes the backing field to `1` instead of calling the setter to initialize it to `-1`.

Comment: To add to what @Aplet123 said.
If you use the setter in an init block, it would work. https://pl.kotl.in/Rcg9CK7fK

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could track the "raw" value separately from the negative value? Something like this:

```
class Foo(input: Int) {
    private var _someField: Int = input
    var someField: Int
        get() = -_someField
        set(value) {
            _someField = -value
        }

    fun bar() {
        println(someField)
    }
}
```

Now the class internals can reference `_someField` to deal directly with the raw value, while outside clients can only "see" `someField`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, in the end there are probably many solutions. I could also define explicit getter and setter functions instead of the implicit ones and use them if needed. Anyway maybe Kotlin does provide this feature and there is no need for weird, voluminous code :D